# Rewrite SQL on a specific content type node on Drupal 7

Tags: nodes, database

I'm trying to rewrite SQL on a specific node type on Drupal 7. I found this, But it only works on Drupal 6-. What's about Drupal 7? Thank you.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.inc/function/db_rewrite_sql/6

Answer (score 0):

While the question is vague as to your purpose, you may be interested in

- [hook_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7)
- [hook_query_TAG_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7)

to alter queries in Drupal 7.

Comment: I wanted to rewrite SQL to query only comments which is not flagged (set to be the best replay) by Best reply module. Can this help me? Thank you again.